# How to reference a variable from a jFrame textfield in multiple other classes without extending

Tags: java, oop, user-interface

I have a program where a user is supposed to enter in a subject, and whatever event they add within an Events table will also have that specific subject within one of its values. The subject is determined through a previous page that asks what type of subject the events are being made under. However, I cannot extend the class I want to use this variable in as it already extends to java.swing. How do I make it so that this variable can be used anywhere else in other classes without extending?

I had a pretty bad comp sci teacher in my first year of comp sci so OOP fundamentals don't come easily to me, so sorry if this is a dumb question >.<!

Comment: You either need to return the value to the caller (possibly via a dialog) or use some kind of observer/delegate/listener pattern which can be used to notify interested parties that some value has been changed

Comment: It might help us understand the problem better if you include in your question a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.